# How to convert md5 32 bytes hash to corresponding sha256 in python

Tags: python, werkzeug

I have a database that contains md5 hashs, i want to convert them to another type of hash so that the users can login to the new website.

I am using the `werkzeug.security` library to generate the hashs.

I there is any way to do that ??

Comment: There is no way to do it, both md5 and sha256 are one-way hashes. Make your users to change passwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MD5 is a one-way hash function, there is no way to reverse it so it can be re-endoded as another type of hash.

The usual approach to this problem is to intercept the login process, obtain the plain text password and encode it separately for the new system. Make sure that you are using a modern password hashing algorithm like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) instead of SHA256.

Comment: So the only way is to let them changing their passwords!

Comment: No, they don't have to change them - as long as you can keep the MD5 hashes around, you can use that for the initial login, then create the SHA256 hash after validating the MD5 hash and remove the old MD5 value from the database.

Comment: Yep, i think this is the best way to handel the situatuin, thanks for your interest :)

Comment: @swordfish just please use something safer than SHA256

Comment: As an example, Django does that automatically as seen in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading). They also describe how to hash insecure hashes within a safer one in the next section.

Comment: I believe that werkzeug is using the NTLM hashs, correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: No, [werkzeug defaults](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/utils/#module-werkzeug.security) to PBKDF2. Apparently with a work factor of 8.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Saying, SHA256 is bad is cutting a few corners. It is common to use bcrypt and scrypt (or PBKDF2) with SHA256 as the algorithm. So, a single pass SHA256 is inferior to several iterations of the algorithm, but the hash is still very valid.

Answer (score 3):

No. Hashes are not reversible, so you can't do that directly.

The way you solve this is that when an old user log in, you validate their password against the md5 hash, and if it matches, you create the SHA256 hash from the plain text password, sets the new SHA256 hash in the database (either as a separate field or by using a hash type identifier in front of the hash itself) and then remove the MD5 hash value.

After a while (for example a year), you remove all the existing MD5 hashes and make people that attempt to log in without a valid hash reset their password through existing means and then only populate the SHA256 field.

Comment: Beat me to it (was 10 seconds from submitting the same answer). This is the only sane way to perform the conversion. The only hashes you could convert yourself are the incredibly weak passwords (which are going to be weak no matter the hash algorithm used), and intentionally attacking your users' passwords *and not telling them they're weak if you succeed* is seriously bad practice.

Comment: If you are going to change all the hashes, consider using a slow hash function (for [safety](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/90065)).

Comment: @Hyarus Agreed.